# Share user defaults between users

Tags: objective-c, macos, share, nsuserdefaults, defaults

I'm using user defaults to store my app data.

I have some global data that is relevant for all users on the same machine.

How can I share this data between them?

NSUserDefaults' [initWithSuiteName](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/initWithSuiteName:) did not work.

The only workaround I found it to write to a hidden file in the root folder, but that is too visible to the users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `/Users/Shared` directory like [iTunes](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203160#scinfo) & the [App Store](http://galvanist.com/post/66313155502/userssharedadi).

Answer (score 1):

The closest you could do is to make all of the users be members of a single group, then make a group writable file with the shared data.  It could be a plist and it could even be accessed via the defaults API, assuming you don't need multiple simultaneous write access.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `CFPreferences` APIs instead of `NSUserDefaults`, passing `kCFPreferencesAnyUser` as the user name parameter.  However, setting defaults for all users requires admin privileges.